# Saving user names for Google OAuth2 WebServerFlow

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-api-client, gmail-api

I have implemented Google's OAuth2 procedure in Python (see this link for tutorial on using OAuth2WebServerFlow: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth) but cannot figure out how to capture who my authenticating user is. I.e., what is their email address? Otherwise when I save their OAuth2 Credentials I don't know who the credentials belong to. Nothing in the auth_uri, flow, or credentials object gives the authenticating user's email address. The second to last line in my code prints out a JSON with keys for the OAuth2Credentials class (http://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/epy/oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials-class.html)

Any ideas? I can't imagine I have to ask the authenticating user for their account information directly...

I'm building an app using the new GMail API and need to offline access to users' accounts.

```
class Auth(app.basic.BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
    flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id=settings.get('google_client_id'),
                       client_secret=settings.get('google_client_secret'),
                       scope=OAUTH_SCOPE,
                       redirect_uri='http://localhost:8001/auth/google/return')
    auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
    return self.redirect(auth_uri)

class AuthReturn(app.basic.BaseHandler):
   def get(self):
   oauth_code = self.get_argument('code', '')
   flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id=settings.get('google_client_id'),
                       client_secret=settings.get('google_client_secret'),
                       scope=OAUTH_SCOPE,
                       redirect_uri='http://localhost:8001/auth/google/return')
   credentials = flow.step2_exchange(oauth_code)
   # Save credentials to database. How do I get the username?
   print credentials.to_json()
   return self.redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is in the scope that you request. I had defined an OAUTH_SCOPE variable that was

```
OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify'
```

But this scope only gives you info as defined by the GMail API, which doesn't include user profile info. So to extend what your credentials will give you, you have to extend the scope of the authentication request:

```
OAUTH_SCOPE = ('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify '
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email '
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile')
```

Running the exact same code with this scope variable will give you access to the userinfo.email and userinfo.email stuff to, which included everything I needed. Note that the scope argument is a space delimited string. It's actually incredibly elegant!

Comment: Please mark your own answer as the accepted answer. Thank you for laying it out the solution, it works great! I tested it for the Google Drive API and it works just as well.